# vscode: Go to definition in other editor pane

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I go to a definition of a function and the file is already open in another tab in the same editor pane, the definition will be shown there. 
However, if the file is open in another editor split screen pane, the file will be opened again in the original editor.

Is it possible to change that behavior? Especially, if the file containing the definition is open in both panes (like when the definition of the function is in the same file where I call `Go to definition`), is there the possibility to jump to that definition in the other editor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you are describing [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/52647)

Should be fixed in VS Code 1.26+ (aka, the current VS Code insiders build)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the same problem. I am still on 1.25. How long does it usually take until the insiders builds are officially released?

Comment: The fix should be in current insiders builds. We release a new one every business day

Answer (score 22):

This is already a setting in version 1.35.1. Look for **"Reveal If Open"** in Settings (`Workbench › Editor: Reveal If Open`)

Answer (score 0):

there is also the `editor.action.revealDefinitionAside` command which will always open the file in another pane.