# "Go to Definition" always in new tab in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I installed VSCode on MAC BigSur. Whenever I click on "Go to Definition" it should open in a **new** tab. How to achieve this?

Currently, only if the definition is present in another file, the definition opens in a new tab. Otherwise if present in the same file it scrolls to the definition in the same file which is not desired. In either case, function definitions should open in a new tab.

Comment: created an improved version of this specifically asking about how to open in split editor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72629558/go-to-definition-in-new-split-editor-i-e-tab

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vscode: Go to definition in other editor pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279506/vscode-go-to-definition-in-other-editor-pane)

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition), you can open the definition to the side with `Ctrl+Alt+Click`.

Comment: I want to open in a new tab not in a new split. I can manage 10 tabs but not 10 splits.

Comment: You cannot open the same file in the same group.