# Go to Definition in new Split Editor (i.e. tab or pane) in vscode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

As an improvement on the [similar existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69924151/go-to-definition-always-in-new-tab-in-vscode) I want to know if there is a way to assign a keyboard shortcut in VSCode to "Go to Definition" in a new split tab.

(A workaround might be to use a second application to assign a shortcut for 1) go-to definition, 2) split editor 3) move to editor left 4) close editor 5) move to editor right, but this seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer here is the `View: Move Editor into Next Group`-shortcut
which opens the editor in the second split pane. However, this only works for two split panes. It does not open a *new* split-pane if there is one already.