# vscode - how to open definition in split pane

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want vscode to open definition of a function/method in another split pane where the file is already open. Is there a shortcut/way to do this ?

I open my spec and code into split panes (say left side is spec and right side the code being tested). When I ctrl-click on the function under test in the spec (function call) it opens the same file in the spec pane. Why ? Why can't it scroll to the function in the already open file in the other pane ?

Or if there is some trick I am missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vscode: Go to definition in other editor pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51279506/vscode-go-to-definition-in-other-editor-pane)

Comment: It doesn't answer what I am asking. I think the answer is "No - not possible" because there is no way (via keyboard shortcuts to decide to open a file in same pane or different pane.